# Detect Windows 8 Mobile?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, browser-feature-detection

I was wondering if this can detect the windows 8 mobile!

```
    <!--[if (gt IE 9)&(IEMobile)]>  
    Win 8 Phone  
    <[endif]-->
```

Having said that IE10 dropped conditional comments, did they implemented same in mobile as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional comments didnt worked on IE10 Mobile as well. Had to go with `navigator.userAgent` string sniffing.

I found a JSfiddle that helps tp achieve the same: http://jsfiddle.net/googabeast/VKAZ8/

Answer (score 2):

IE 10 does not support conditional comments in any devices. EI10 also have removed their proprietary filters from it.

For any mobile device detection - http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

Reinventing wheel does not have any valid points.